# javascript dates compare

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

I'm working with javascript Date and i'm starting to go crazy :)

I want two compare only the year,month, day of two dates. The date are (retrieve from firebug stacktrace):

```
[Date {Thu Feb 11 2010 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}]

[Date {Sun Jul 11 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}]
```

In this point i'm trying compare the two dates like this:

```
if (datepickerBegin == null || datepickerBegin.length == 0 || datepickerBegin != date) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

This code obvious doesn't work, which is the simple way of comparing these two String?

I'm trying to convert this var to Date and concatenate into another var the `getMonth()+getYear()+getDay()`... but
i believe that there is a easiest way.

By the way, why the following line give `NaN`

```
new Date(datepickerBegin).getMonth()
```

but the following line works?

```
new Date(Date.parse(datepickerBegin.toString())).getMonth()
```

Comment: I believe you can replace the line with: Date.parse(datepickerBegin.toString()).getMonth()

Comment: The NaN issue is because it is expecting a string and its getting an int instead.

Comment: @benams: Nope, `Date.parse()` returns a `number`, milliseconds since Epoch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the dates to time, using the `.getTime()` method. If the dates are equal, they will have the same values returned from getTime. This assumes that you're only using string values for your dates (ie "9/6/12"). If your dates will have time stamps associated with them, then you'll need to use the `setHours()` function to set all the time reference to 0 (`d.setHours(0,0,0,0);`).

**Links:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

**Example:**

```
if(datePickerBegin.getTime() === datePickerEnd.getTime())
{
  //...do something.
}
```

**Note:** If you do end up going the `.getMonth()` route, then be aware that the function returns the months as zero based numbers, so add 1 to what it returns.

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the dates using `Date.parse(...);`, you can use the Date constructor to create date types like so. An example of this process has been abstracted into the function below:

```
function parseDateAsDatePart(dateString) {
    var parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
    return new Date(parsedDate.getYear(), parsedDate.getMonth(), parsedDate.getDate());
}
```

Once you change both strings into Date objects, you may compare them as shown above.

**Note:** as Linus mentioned above, `Date.parse(...)` returns an integer, not a date object, so it needs to be wrapped in the Date constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with getMonth, GetDays , ...

http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html